# Hooking into the bootstrapping process of an Angular-CLI generated app

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-cli

I want to delay the bootstraping of my Angular-CLI app to let my loading animation finish before the actual  is rendered. When root component is bootstrapped, this css animation content will automatically be stripped out. This gives little control over the user experience (UX) since the "child content" is instantaneously removed from the DOM (Document Object Model).

Therefore, the idea is to move the css animation content out of the  element and instead define it outside but remove it from the view programatically after the animation has finished.

I tried to do exactly what's described [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3105-creating-a-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm), but the problem is that it doesn't seem to work that way with angular-cli generated apps anymore. It works as described with pre-angular-cli generated apps that rely on SystemJS directly, though.

Since Angular-cli abstracted away a lot of this, I can't hook myself into that life-cycle anymore (this way). Does anyone know how I can hook myself into the bootstraping life-cycle of an angular-cli generated app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright folks,

I ended up using [this approach](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3151-revisited-creating-an-event-driven-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-0-0.htm) and it worked fine. It doesn't deal with any of the SystemJS stuff.